# Data Table loads only last record of mysqlDataReader

Tags: asp.net

In my page mysqlDataReader returns 4 records.Whenever I load this mysqlDataReader to DataTable 
using

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Load(dr);
```

DataTable shows only last record.

my Code is:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < gvDemoBatches.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvDemoBatches.Rows[i].FindControl("checkSelect");
     if (cb.Checked == true)
     {
         Panel2.Visible = true;
         objBEBatch.BatchID = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)gvDemoBatches.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("lblBatchId")).Text);
          MySqlDataReader dr = objBLAddNewDemo.GetParticularDemoData(objBEBatch);
         dt.Clear();
         dt.Load(dr);
      }
 }
```

"GetParticularDemoData" stored Procedure Returns 7 rows.but datatable shows only last record.

Thanks in Advance,
Ratnam.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are iterating your reading with clearing your table on each iteration. Try to use DataAdapter instead

```
 var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query);
 adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

First please write proper/full code so one can understand !
According to your code, dr is a data row,and dr will contain single row at a time,
It seems you may have taken dr in loop,so at last it will contain last record only.

so your data table displays last record.!

Answer (score 0):

your are adding rows to datatable inside loop. So the last loop record will be saved in the datatable

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvDemoBatches.Rows.Count; i++)
{
```

will execute multiple times and inside this you have

```
 MySqlDataReader dr = objBLAddNewDemo.GetParticularDemoData(objBEBatch);
 dt.Clear();
 dt.Load(dr);
```

So the data table will contain the data only for the last row of the `gridview` where `cb.Checked == true)`

Comment: Data is not in gridview. It is in dr. I traied in that way also,but it is not working